# How to fix this error 404 NOT FOUND laraval index page show?

Tags: laravel

I am getting this error on home page what is the reason for this error. I have tried many times but could not fix this error. I have given DATABASE NAME correctly in DATABASE .ENV. Below are some pictures please note it.

index.page

[image]

Database

[image]

.env

```
    APP_NAME=Reward-App
APP_ENV=production
APP_KEY=base64:t9Pl+P0jnbnmS2tNpEuh4CT+x+T6xZrKcDhGb1oOCJ4=
APP_DEBUG=false
APP_URL=

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=test3
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=
MAIL_PASSWORD=
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_BUCKET=

HEADER_USER=rewardfsJGSA


PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

Comment: If the database is wrong, you get **500**, not **404**. It's something else

Comment: @Abdulla Nilam  how

Comment: You're accessing *admin*, is the admin route exist with the correct path?

Comment: Firstly check the path and route as provided if everything is good then just check that .htaccess Is available at the root of the project and in a public directory.
It is not a 500 server error so you don't need to check the .env file.
Still not work:
And just hit URL like htt://localhost/admin/public
Or just hit URL like htt://localhost/admin/public/index.php